# StaticInjectionError in ng-bootstrap

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

Need to implement a rating system in my project so i tried with ng-bootstrap modules and used below code:

```
<ngb-rating [(rate)]="currentRate"></ngb-rating>
```

But it makes error while running on browser:

```
ng:///AppModule/SearchResultsComponent.ngfactory.js:55 ERROR Error: StaticInjectorError[NgbRatingConfig]: 
  StaticInjectorError[NgbRatingConfig]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for NgbRatingConfig!
    at _NullInjector.get (webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:1190)
    at resolveToken (webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:1478)
    at tryResolveToken (webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:1420)
    at StaticInjector.get (webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:1291)
    at resolveToken (webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:1478)
    at tryResolveToken (webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:1420)
    at StaticInjector.get (webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:1291)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:11075)
    at NgModuleRef_.get (webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:12307)
    at resolveDep (webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:12805)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have imported**`NgbModule`** in app.module.ts

```
import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

imports:      [ 
  NgbModule.forRoot(),
]
```

Comment: i just input NgModule without .forRoot() that is the problem it made error thanks